# xen-4 single nic dom0, add second bridge

Tags: bridge, xen

im running xen4, my dom0 is debian6

It has a single nic and im having hard problems creating a second bridge to have two virtual nics inside my guest.

i tought on using dummy dev, but i had read somewhere than its a xen3 option and it might be deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dummy dev as a internal bridge.

```
auto dummy0
iface dummy0 inet manual
re-up ifconfig $IFACE up
post-down ifconfig $IFACE down

auto xenbrdummy
iface xenbrdummy inet manual
bridge_ports dummy0
bridge_maxwait 0
bridge_stp off
```

Reference is here:
http://wiki.xensource.com/xenwiki/HostConfiguration/Networking